# pytest-qt waitSignal for long running computation running in a thread pool

Tags: pyqt5, pytest-qt

I have successfully implemented a Python Qt app based off [this](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyside6-applications-qthreadpool/) very nice tutorial.

I am now writing tests using **[pytest-qt](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)** to specifically test a button that triggers a long running computation that eventually emits a signal when finished. I would like to use waitSignal as documented [here](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html).

```
def test_long_computation(qtbot):
app = Application()

# Watch for the app.worker.finished signal, then start the worker.
with qtbot.waitSignal(app.worker.finished, timeout=10000) as blocker:
    blocker.connect(app.worker.failed)  # Can add other signals to blocker
    app.worker.start()
    # Test will block at this point until either the "finished" or the
    # "failed" signal is emitted. If 10 seconds passed without a signal,
    # TimeoutError will be raised.

assert_application_results(app)
```

When the button is clicked, this function is executed:

```
def on_button_click_function(self):
    """
    start thread pool to run function
    """
    # Pass the function to execute
    worker = Worker(self.execute_check_urls)
    worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)  # type: ignore
    worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)  # type: ignore
    worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)  # type: ignore
    # Execute
    log_info("Starting thread pool worker ...")
    self.threadpool.start(worker).
```

And when the thread completes, a signal is emitted

```
def thread_complete(self):
    main_window = self.find_main_window()
    if main_window:
        main_window.button_click_signal.emit(
            self.results
        )
        log_info(
            f"Emitted signal for button click function: {self.results}"
        )
```

Below is the init function of the main class:

```
class MyClass:

def __init__(
    self,
    *args,
    **kwargs
):
    super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
    print(
        "Multithreading with max %d threads"
        % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount()
    ).
```

And the worker class which is QRunnable:

```
def __init__(
    self,
    fn,
    *args,
    **kwargs
):
    super(Worker, self).__init__()
    self.fn = fn
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.signals = WorkerSignals()
    self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

@Slot()
def run(self):
    try:
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    except (Exception):
        traceback.print_exc()
        exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
        self.signals.error.emit(
            (exctype, value, traceback.format_exc())
        )
    else:
        self.signals.result.emit(result)
    finally:
        self.signals.finished.emit().
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to access the worker object from the threadpool. I also tested qtbot.mouseClick() which triggers the function but never emits the signal.

Comment: I suppose that `Worker` is a QRunnable, but it's difficult to know that as you didn't provide a valid [mre]. Besides, what do you mean by "how to access the worker object from the threadpool"? You cannot get QRunnable objects from it, it only manages the treads in which they are executed, it's up to you to keep trace of them. Please clarify what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I added the worker class code and yes it is QRunnable. The end goal is to test a long running function that is triggered on a button click and emits a signal when the thread completes. I am struggling to use pytest-qt waitSignal function to detect the emit signal.